# How to filter mat table dataSource based on two columns entered and clicked on search button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have mat table data displayed for columns - Role, Status, Email iD, Name. And above that table, i have given option like search area where user try to enter the value of Role and value of Status and clicks on Search button. if those two values entered by user are exactly matched out for a row then it has to show that row data only otherwise it has to show no rows found.I tried to user filterPredicate method to match with respective object values but could not able to crack it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare a filter predicate after creating a new `MatTableDataSource`.

```
filterObj: {role: string, status: string} = {role: null, status: null}; // <-- declare this at the start of your component.

this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (myObject, filter) => {
  let filterObj: {role: string, status: string} = JSON.parse(filter);
  if(((filterObj.role && filterObj.role != '') ? myObject.role == filterObj.role : true) && ((filterObj.status && filterObj.status != '') ? myObject.status == filterObj.status : true)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And maybe you call an `applyFilter` function on `keyup` in you `matInput`. I always have a function where I can set a filter determined on the type I give my function. Don`t forget to store your filter object in this case in your component.

```
applyFilter(value: string,type: string) {
  switch(type) {
    case 'role':
      this.filterObj.role = value;
      break;
    case 'status':
      this.filterObj.status = value;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterObj);
}
```

That should work for you.

Comment: Hi, it worked as expected. I was missing correct way of coding in filter Predicate method before. Thanks a lot. It has added some knowledge by your approach.

Comment: Where should I put `this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (myObject, filter) =>...` and from where I get filter string?

Comment: I finaly made it. Insted of `myObject.status == filterObj.status` I used `data.name.indexOf(filterObj.name) != -1` to check if substring is matching and not a whole word

Answer (score 0):

For custom filter, we've to define filterPredicate function after creating a new MatTableDataSource like

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<dataType>(this.data);
this.datasource.filterPredicate = (data: dataType, filtersJson: string) {
  const matchFilter = [];
  const filters = JSON.parse(filtersJson);
  filters.forEach((filter) => {
  const val = data[filter.id] === null ? '' : data[filter.id];
    matchFilter.push(val.toLowerCase().includes(filter.value.toLowerCase()));
  });
  return matchFilter.some(Boolean);
}
```

Here dataType is the Interface for table row data.

filterPredicate function will be executed for each table row by angular.

In the html you can use event binding like

```
<input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Search by columnName1 or columnName2 or ...."
    (keyup)="onSearch($event.target.value)"
/>
```

& you need to define the onSearch funtion in class like

```
onSearch(value) {
  const tableFilters = [];
  tableFilters.push(
    {
     id: 'columnName1',
      value: value,
    },
    {
      id: 'columnName2',
      value: value,
    }
  );
  this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(tableFilters);
}
```

You can add n numbers of column to fiter the data by adding objs in tableFilters.

**That's it. Hurreeee...!!!**